# Volumetric Lighting looking very bad

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I've tried increasing all sorts of samples yet the lighting looks terrible (Even on render!) How do i fix this? This is eevee 2.81.
[image]

Comment: This isn't the correct place you should be putting these questions in https://blenderartists.org/

Comment: What is your current node setup for the volume?